# VBA-JSON to import data from all pages in one table

Tags: json, excel, vba, web-scraping

I have web scraped data from web, but my program was working for a single page, now that I have created an outer loop so that program will fetch the similar set of data from all pages of link it giving an error i.e end with without with. Since I am new to vba, any expert help required to sort this issue out.
Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FetchTabularInfo()
    Dim Http As New XMLHTTP60, Html As New HTMLDocument
    Dim col As Variant, icol As New Collection
    Dim csrf As Variant, i&
    Dim s As String, re As Object, p As String, page As Long, rx As String 'Variable Definations
    Const START_PAGE As Long = 1
    Const END_PAGE As Long = 4
    Const RESULTS_PER_PAGE As Long = 40

p = "\[{""@context"".*?\]"
    Set re = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        For page = START_PAGE To END_PAGE

    With Http
        .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/2620/10/1", False
        .send
        Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    With Html.querySelectorAll(".table tr a[onclick^='show_ngo_info']")
        For i = 0 To .Length - 1
            icol.Add Split(Split(.Item(i).getAttribute("onclick"), "(""")(1), """)")(0)
        Next i
    End With

    Dim r As Long, headers(), results(), ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("SrNo", "Name of VGO/NGO", "Address", "City", "State", "Tel", "Mobile", "Web", "Email")
    ReDim results(1 To icol.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)

    For Each col In icol
        r = r + 1
        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf", False
            .send
            csrf = .responseText
        End With

        csrf = Split(Replace(Split(csrf, ":")(1), """", ""), "}")(0)

        Dim json As Object
        With Http
            .Open "POST", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", False
            .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
            .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
            .send "id=" & col & "&csrf_test_name=" & csrf
            Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)

            Dim orgName As String, address As String, so As Long, city As String
            Dim state As String, tel As String, mobile As String, website As String, email As String

            On Error Resume Next
            orgName = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_orgName")
            address = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_add")
            city = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_city")
            srNo = r '<unsure where this is coming from.
            state = Replace$(json("registeration_info")(1)("StateName"), "amp;", vbNullString)
            tel = IIf(IsNull(json("infor")("0")("Off_phone1")), vbNullString, json("infor")("0")("Off_phone1")) '<unsure where this is coming from. Need a csrf to test with
            mobile = json("infor")("0")("Mobile")
            website = json("infor")("0")("ngo_url")
            email = json("infor")("0")("Email")
            On Error GoTo 0

            Dim arr()
            arr = Array(srNo, orgName, address, city, state, tel, mobile, website, email)
            For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
               results(r, i + 1) = arr(i)
            Next
        End With
    Next col
    With ws
        .Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers
        .Cells(2, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    End With
    
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: "giving an error" is not a useful description of your specific problem.  Please edit your question to add a description of what's actually happening when you run your code.

Comment: Why do you have a nested with?

`With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")`

I don't see you ever use this?

Comment: I want all pages it is showing results of page 1 previously.

Comment: Your `For`'s and `Next`'s don't seem to match up.  I think you never close the `For page = START_PAGE To END_PAGE` loop.

Comment: Can you sort this out, I don't know how to do it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an outer loop over pages and concatenate page number into url.

`r` needs to be reset to 0 at start of each new page.

You need to find last used row irrespective of column each time you write out current page's array (or dimension one huge array at start and populate that - then write out just once to sheet).

Remove autoinstantiation.

I see what looks like duplicated info in output so worth looking into data source regarding that.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub FetchTabularInfo()
    Dim Http As XMLHTTP60, Html As HTMLDocument, col As Variant, csrf As Variant, i&, page As Long
    Dim headers(), ws As Worksheet, iCol As Collection

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    headers = Array("SrNo", "Name of VGO/NGO", "Address", "City", "State", "Tel", "Mobile", "Web", "Email")
    Set Http = New XMLHTTP60
    Set Html = New HTMLDocument

    ws.Cells(1, 1).Resize(1, UBound(headers) + 1) = headers

    For page = 1 To 4

        With Http
            .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/home/statewise_ngo/76/35/" & CStr(page), False
            .send
            Html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With
        Set iCol = New Collection
        With Html.querySelectorAll(".table tr a[onclick^='show_ngo_info']")
            For i = 0 To .Length - 1
                iCol.Add Split(Split(.item(i).getAttribute("onclick"), "(""")(1), """)")(0)
            Next i
        End With

        Dim r As Long, results()
        ReDim results(1 To iCol.Count, 1 To UBound(headers) + 1)
        r = 0
        For Each col In iCol
            r = r + 1
            With Http
                .Open "GET", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/get_csrf", False
                .send
                csrf = .responseText
            End With

            csrf = Split(Replace(Split(csrf, ":")(1), """", ""), "}")(0)

            Dim json As Object
            With Http
                .Open "POST", "https://ngodarpan.gov.in/index.php/ajaxcontroller/show_ngo_info", False
                .setRequestHeader "X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest"
                .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8"
                .send "id=" & col & "&csrf_test_name=" & csrf
                Set json = JsonConverter.ParseJson(.responseText)

                Dim orgName As String, address As String, srNo As Long, city As String
                Dim state As String, tel As String, mobile As String, website As String, email As String

                On Error Resume Next
                orgName = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_orgName")
                address = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_add")
                city = json("registeration_info")(1)("nr_city")
                srNo = r                         '<unsure where this is coming from.
                state = Replace$(json("registeration_info")(1)("StateName"), "amp;", vbNullString)
                tel = IIf(IsNull(json("infor")("0")("Off_phone1")), vbNullString, json("infor")("0")("Off_phone1")) '<unsure where this is coming from. Need a csrf to test with
                mobile = json("infor")("0")("Mobile")
                website = json("infor")("0")("ngo_url")
                email = json("infor")("0")("Email")
                On Error GoTo 0

                Dim arr()
                arr = Array(srNo, orgName, address, city, state, tel, mobile, website, email)
                For i = LBound(headers) To UBound(headers)
                    results(r, i + 1) = arr(i)
                Next
            End With
        Next col
        Set iCol = Nothing: Set json = Nothing
        ws.Cells(GetLastRow(ws) + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(results, 1), UBound(results, 2)) = results
    Next
End Sub

Public Function GetLastRow(ByVal sh As Worksheet) As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    GetLastRow = sh.Cells.Find(What:="*", _
                               After:=sh.Range("A1"), _
                               Lookat:=xlPart, _
                               LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                               SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                               SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, _
                               MatchCase:=False).Row
    On Error GoTo 0
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, it is working great, but one issue is that if I run loop for the number of pages like 30 and pages on the web is 8 then it is fetching the results correctly but giving a subscript output of range error.

Comment: you need to see if there is a way to determine the total number of pages from the html in your first xmlhttp. Do an intiial request to page 1,determine max number of pages, then if more than 1 page do a loop up until required number of pages or max number of pages.